# TabBarController not loading data after I signed in with Apple and present wievController?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

Good morning. I have ran into an issue on my current project.. when I sign in with any other social network the uitabBarController works perfectly everything and every page works and load xml and JSon data.. but whenever I Sign In with Apple. only first tab in UitabBarController shows data, and every other tab is blank like the storyboard.. I use presentModalStyle= .fullscreen to present tabBar after Apple sign in. Can someone tell me if it’s a bug